# Detect Facebook App Canvas Unloaded

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, sdk

I need to detect that a user unloads my Facebook app (navigates to somewhere else or logs out of Facebook).  How can this be done?  I have tried:

```
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.logout', function(response) {
    console.log('logged out');    
});
```

But this never fires :(

Comment: This only fires on FB.logout(); right?!?!

Comment: Docs say "fired when the user logs out".  Does not fire me when I logout of facebook in the browser with my app open.  Obviously I need to look deeper and figure out why.  However, what I really want is to know when the app is shown and when is is not.  I cannot find an event for that one but surely there is a good way.

Comment: I think I was not seeing this event because my console log was being cleared...  I believe it was firing when I logged out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why not try to listen to the window unload event rather than using the Facebook API:

```
window.addEventListener('unload', function(event) {
   console.log('Bye bye!');
});
```

This should catch the situations you need

Comment: @MiguelAlejandroFuentesLopez This will fire whenever the page is changed. I'm the one person on Earth who doesn't use facebook and so I can't say for sure, but I suspect that when a user logs out, they are taken to a new page (rather than it happening via AJAX). If you wish to check for both (which will help if the user logs out in another tab), it is trivial to combine mine and the OP's solution. However, I suspect in most cases it is only the current tab that matters, not whether the user has logged out by other means